# JQuery Carousel Delay on Animate Left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you consider the following Pen: http://codepen.io/jhealey5/pen/Lqyhu - And click the Left/Right buttons, you should see that while left works fine, there's a slight delay on the right one.

I understand there's a little more happening with the right button, it's having to move it before it animates, but is there any way to alleviate the problem? Other than purposely delaying the left animation that is.

And any other improvements are a bonus.

jQuery code:

```
    var $left = $('#left'),
        $right = $('#right'),
        $images = $('.items img'),
        isAnimating = 0;

    $left.on('click', function(){
      if (isAnimating) {
        return false;
      } else {
        var $item = $('.items img:eq(0)');
        $item.velocity({'margin-left': '-100%'}, 400, 'easeOut', function(){
            $(this).appendTo('.items .wrapper').css('margin-left', 0);
        });
        isAnimating = 0;
      }
    });

    $right.on('click', function(){
      if (isAnimating) {
        return false;
      } else {
        isAnimating = 1;
        var $item = $('.items img:eq(0)'),
            $lastItem = $('.items img:eq('+($images.length-1)+')');

        $lastItem.prependTo('.items .wrapper').css('margin-left', '-100%').velocity({
          'margin-left': 0
        }, 350, 'easeOut');
        isAnimating = 0;
      }

    });
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using "-100%" try to do it in px.

```
 $imgWidth = $images.width(); // Add this variable


$left.on('click', function(){

  if (isAnimating) {
    return false;
  } else {
    var $item = $('.items img:eq(0)');
    $item.velocity({'margin-left': -$imgWidth},
      400, 'easeOut', function(){
        $(this).appendTo('.items .wrapper').css('margin-left', 0);
    });
    isAnimating = 0;
  }
});

$right.on('click', function(){
  if (isAnimating) {
    return false;
  } else {

    var $lastItem = $('.items img:eq('+($images.length-1)+')');

    $lastItem.prependTo('.items .wrapper')
    .css('margin-left', -$imgWidth).velocity({
      'margin-left': 0
    }, 400, 'easeOut');
    isAnimating = 0;
  }

});
```

Comment: Oh wow, that fixed it. Never would of thought it would of been something like that... Do you happen to know why this fixed it? As in why the percentage method for doing it would slow down one side but not the other?

Comment: Yes the % method is always slower and it is always adviced to set in pixels when doing it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The integer in the second variable of the velocity function needs to be decreased to speed this up. 
Try for example changing 350 to 100 to see the response rate increase.

Comment: That just changes the speed at which the animation happens, I tried setting it slightly faster than the other in hopes it would help, but it didn't. Setting it to 100 just makes that side super fast.